# Importing Excel sheet values in Web SQL

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am intending to create a Database ( Web SQL ) , and trying to insert the values in that database by importing an Excel Sheet just for first time.
How to insert the values only for once from the excel and not considering it further , just considering the data .

```
var db = openDatabase ("Test", "1.0", "Test", 65535);
db.transaction (function (transaction) 
{
alert('In ()');
var sql = "CREATE TABLE customers " +
" (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
"fname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " + 
"lname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)" 

 transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, function ()
{ 
 alert ("Table created");
});
 });
db.transaction (function (transaction) 
{
 var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (lname, fname) VALUES (?, ?)";
}
```

The above is my websql and the final insert statement , i want to import from Excel sheet.
Thanks

Comment: IIRC http://sheetjs.com/websql/ does precisely that (generate sql statements from excel sheet and load into websql)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly abt websql,this is more with mysql,but will give you brief idea, I refered somewhere
Lets your table be like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentdata`(
  `StudentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `MobileNo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Code for uploading file and extracting somedata from it

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_FILES['csvFile']['name']!="")
    {   $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".csv"),"excel_file");
        $row=0;
        if(($handle = fopen("excel/".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $num = count($data);
                $query="INSERT INTO StudentData(FirstName,LastName,MobileNo,City)
                                VALUES('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."')";
                mysql_query($query);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
    else if($_FILES['excelFile']['name']!="")
    {
        $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".xls",".xlsx"),"excel_file");
        $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
        $data->read('excel_file/'.$fileName);
        for($i=1;$i<=$data->sheets[0]['numRows'];$i++)
        {
            $firstname=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];
            $lastname=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2];
            $mobile=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];
            $city=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4];
            $query="INSERT INTO StudentData(FirstName,LastName,MobileNo,City)
                        VALUES('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$mobile."','".$city."')";
            mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
}
```

For further study and reference you can get it from here.
[Excel to php and mysql](http://demos.9code.in/excelToSql/)

Hope this would give you the idea,